# Bash scripting--regular expressions. regmatch.unix

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to write a bash script(unix) that can compare the files in a folder and match them with files in another folder and detect if matches exists.

The files in the folders all have a common name structure like :

```
*****-dbtableName-*****-YYYY-MM-DD.sql
```

I have tried `[[a-zA-Z]+\DB[A-Z]+\-[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[sql]` as a regular expression. Its not working.

I´ll be greatfull for any help.

Comment: do the files really have '*' chars in their names? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter based on the regex he provided seems that `*` means anything in that filename example (ie the filename is a regex itself! :P)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried diff?

`diff -q directory1 directory2` will report on files that don't exist in both directories or  whether they are are identical or not. You can always pipe the results through grep if you want to filter further or use the `-x` option to exclude particular filetypes from diff. Try `info diff` for more details on the version on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a name like: *barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql* a match can be analyzed like that:

```
[a-zA-Z]\+-[a-zA-Z]\+DB-[a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\.sql
```

using eg. `grep`

```
$ echo "barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql" | grep "[a-zA-Z]\+-[a-zA-Z]\+DB-[a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\.sql"
barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql   # matched
```

you can optimize it like this

```
[a-zA-Z-]\+DB-[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+\.sql
```

which wouldn't be as strict but still matches the correct filename

```
$ echo "barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql" | grep "[a-zA-Z-]\+DB-[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+\.sql"
barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql   # matched
```

or if you prefer this example

```
$ touch /tmp/barbar-fooDB-bazbaz-2011-06-19.sql
$ ls -1 /tmp/ | grep "[a-zA-Z-]\+DB-[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+\.sql"
```

---

This is all good for dealing with the regex, but for your problem it maybe better to take Dan's advice and use `diff` combining it with a wildcard like `*.sql` or whatever fits your needs.